# Why ssh tunnel cannot create in the virtualbox or qemu with force mode (-f)?

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, ssh-tunnel, debian-wheezy, qemu

I try
on the dedicated server

```
root@debian:~# strace -e open -f sshpass -p guest ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null guest@198.51.100.11 -C -N -D 127.0.0.1:22220 -f
[pid 10451] open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)    = 4
[pid 10451] open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)    = 4
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to 198.51.100.11 ([198.51.100.11:22).
debug1: Local connections to 127.0.0.1:22220 forwarded to remote address socks:0
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 22220.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
^CProcess 10451 detached
root@debian:~# debug1: channel 0: free: port listener, nchannels 1
debug1: Killed by signal 1.
^C
```

this is all right

and I try on the debian 7.7 x64 installed on the virtualbox or qemu

```
root@debian:~# strace -e open -f sshpass -p guest ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null guest@198.51.100.11 -C -N -D 127.0.0.1:22220 -f
Warning: Permanently added '198.51.100.11' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
[pid 10454] open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)    = 4
[pid 10454] open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)    = 4
Process 10455 attached
Process 10454 detached
[pid 10453] --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGHUP (Hangup) @ 0 (0) ---
Process 10455 detached
root@debian:~#
```

why ssh tunnel do not work on the virtualbox or qemu?
ssh tunel work on  the virtualbox or qemu with option `-v` verbose, but whit option `-f`  do not work

Comment: You should explain in more detail how those nodes are connected network-wise.

Comment: virtualbox and qemu connected network bridge